# IDE for debugging Django project

Tags: django, ide

I am new in `django` driven web application development and currently I am working on a project. I use `sublime text 3` as my text editor. But it's seems hard to me to understand what is going on under the hood. Is there a way of debugging `django` application like in debugging `C#` `.NET` application in `VS`? I searched and found that many programmers suggest `vim` and checked it out. But it slows my development more.
How to get familiar fast with `django`?

Comment: Please do not discourage this question by down voting. I really need to know what the experts are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pycharm (community version is free) will allow you to create a django runserver config and will then allow you to put in breakpoints etc like visual studio.

Edit: on further study, the  free version of pycharm might not have Django support http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Pycharm is the best experience for codding and even learning the good way to code python. And have a nice debugger too. I use the community version, every day working with Django. I used Eclipse + PyDev before, and I like vim too. But I choose Pycharm as the better choice.

Comment: Thanks PyCharm is a nice IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried  [django debug toolbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar)? It is useful when you develop without an IDE. and there are tools on *nix systems but i think you are using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I find WingIDE (http://wingware.com/) a very attractive environment, especially for Django. It is *not* free but (I think) affordable.

If anything goes wrong with the django server, you are kicked back into the Wing debugger. You can select any level in the exception backtrace and are sent to the code position. You can then interactively play with the code in the "Debug probe" -- a python shell, looking at the state of local variables etc. Some (but not all) errors in template rendering send you back directly to the trouble making template line. You can of course also set breakpoints, fire up your server, then first play around with the code in the Debug probe (even changing variables) and continue. It's really well done, I think. Almost as good as emacs ;)